# confusion about lists and pairs

Tags: c++, list, iterator, size, ifstream

So I'm experimenting with trying to add first and last names into a double linked list.
I have a various text files of different lengths with the format "string, string", and am using list> to store my data.

I am using this code:

```
typedef std::list< std::pair<string,string> > listPair;
```

...

```
list<pair<string, string> > mylist;
ifstream myFile; 
myFile.open("20.txt");

pair<string, string> stuff;
while (myFile >> stuff.first >> stuff.second)
{
    mylist.push_back(stuff);
}

listPair::iterator iter = mylist.begin();

for(;iter != mylist.end();iter++)
{
    string s = (*iter).first;
    cout << s << endl;
    string c = (*iter).second;
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

now the problem i'm having is that firstly, the last item in the list is not being added. 
like every file just misses the end line, so that's a little confusing.

also, I'm doing a "mylist.size()" to ensure all the names have been added, and it's confusing me because say for a text file containing 99 names, i.e 99 lines of text, it will say (not forgetting it only reads in 98 due to missing the last line) that the list has size 48.

WHY 48? 
Is it something to do because I have done pairs, which still would not make sense as if it was not reading in pairs there would actually be double the about, since the pairs are just to take the first and last name as one value.

Mind boggling to me.

once again thanks for all your help!

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `getline`?

Comment: Just as a side note, as a general-purpose container you should use `vector` rather than `list`. From the way you are using it, I do not see the need for a `list` here.

Comment: Could you add the input file `20.txt` (or at least an extract)? Maybe your input isn't properly formatted.

Comment: Your code is correct, although it doesn't account for poorly-formatted input.  That said, your input is poorly-formatted.  Try a text file with 2 names and show us the text file and the results.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but `std::pair` isn't really appropriate here; you have a first name and a last name, but in a `pair` object they are referred to as `first` and `second`. Better to write a struct that holds the two string objects; that gives you the chance to provide better names, and leaves more flexibility if you later need to add additional data members (age, height, weight, bank balance...).

Comment: Reduce the size of your input file and try again. If you still get failures, they'll be much easier to track down. Try it with two entries and with three.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a feeling your file doesn't actually have spaces between the values as you've described, so it looks like this:

```
one,two
three,four
five,six
seven,eight
nine,ten
```

If you were to run your program on this, the size of the `list` will be 2 (`floor(number_of_lines/2)`, which for you would give 48) and the last line won't have been put in the `list` at all. Why?

Firstly, each call to `std::ifstream::operator>>(std::string&)` will extract up until it hits some white space. In this case, the first white space on the first line is the `\n` at the end of it. So on the first iteration, `stuff.first` will be `"one,two"` and then the next line will be read into `stuff.second`, making it `"three,four"`. This is then pushed into the `list`. The next two lines are read in the same way, giving you the pair `{"five,six","seven,eight"}`. On the next iteration, the first `operator>>` will extract `"nine,ten"` and the second will fail, causing the `while` condition to end and the last line to be discarded.

Even if you did have spaces, you would end up with commas in the `first` of every `pair`, which is certainly not what you want.

The nicer way to approach a problem like this is to use `std::getline` to extract a line, and then parse that line as appropriate:

```
std::string line;
std::pair<std::string, std::string> line_pair;
while (std::getline(myFile, line)) {
  std::stringstream line_stream(line);
  std::getline(line_stream, line_pair.first, ',');
  std::getline(line_stream, line_pair.second);
  mylist.push_back(line_pair);
}
```

I also recommend using `std::vector` unless you have a good reason to use `std::list`.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly my issue and it worked perfectly!
gosh learn something new every day haha

Answer (score -1):

Operator >> on ifstream treats newline as yet another token. Hence it will probably read your first and second word as per normal from your first line, but the third token read is the new line on the first line.

Try using getline to 'eat' the newline as well.

Comment: Extractors treat new lines just like any other white space. You don't have to skip around them if you consistently use `operator>>`.